# Cachegrind /Valgrind much more Refs than usually

Tags: c++, caching, valgrind, cachegrind

So I've tried running a C++ code with with the cachegrind tool and it's showing way more refs than when I ran last time which was 2 years ago. Of course I ran it multiple times on both occasions with similar results each time.I'm using the same hardware environment as before.

[This is the old run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJQ1P.jpg)

[This is the new run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohnFh.jpg)

Now the weird thing is it's showing approximately the same amount of cache misses, but with the big change in refs the overall percentage of misses is completely different. This is not desirable for me because the purpose of the runs are to show the inefficiency of linked lists with regards to the cache. On the old run the results were, as expected, a high percentage of cache misses.

Of course I tried it with multiple versions of valgrind including the one I used back then. The results were, as they should be, the same.

Anyone have an explanation for this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you building with the same optimization level?  Disabling optimizations will result in significantly more memory accesses in general.

Comment: In the latest Valgrind, Cachegrind cache modeling has been turned off by default. The cache model is not realistic enough to be of much value.